# Is it better to have one model with more categories or less with two for multi-label classification?

Tags: classification, unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning, multilabel-classification, semi-supervised-learning

For classifying text into three classes *question*, *complain* and  *complements*
where each sample can have multi-labels (question and complains,  question and complements):

- is it better to have **one model** for all three targets?
- or **two models**, the **first** for (question or not) and the **second** one for (complains, complements or else)?

which approach is better when the data are labeled, unlabeled and unbalanced?

Comment: What do you mean about the data being unlabelled? You can't do classification without labels, you can only do clustering.

Answer (score 0):

Generally there are two main options for multi-label classifications:

- A binary model for every class, in this case the labels are supposed to be independent of each other.
- A joint model which learns all the classes together, so at training stage the class represents the three values for the labels, for instance:

  - class "NNN" means no label at all
  - class "NNY" means no for question, no for complain and yes for complements
  - class "NYN" means no for question, yes for complain and no for complements
  - ...
  - class "YYY" means yes for question, yes for complain and yes for complements

In theory there are $2^3$ possible classes for 3 labels, but in practice there might be less combinations in the data (as suggested in the question). If the labels depend on each other (for instance if it's unlikely to have a document which is both complain and complements), a joint model is more appropriate. However a joint model might need more instances to be trained properly, since it has more work to do than a binary model.